# Creating an alarm at a certain date and time

Tags: java, android, events, notifications, alarm

I am trying to get an alarm or notification to go at a certain time and date.  I want to be able to have multiple alarms for specific dates in an array.  I don't know where to continue off of having my button working:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   // button.setOnClickListener(this);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {

             if (checkBox.isChecked()) {



             }

        }
```

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

This [tutorial](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) is a pretty simple example how to use it.

Another simple [exmaple](http://n8tech44.blogspot.com/2012/06/using-android-alarmmanager-to-schedule.html) that breaks it down into the basic steps of

1. Creating an event
2. Creating a BroadcastReceiver to handle the event

**EDIT**
To make a notification, modify the broadcast receiver to create a notification when the alarm event is received.

[Android Status Notification Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) shows pretty well the basic steps to create a notification.

1. Get a reference to the NotificationManager
2. Create a notification instance.  You can then define an image, text, and time which would just be the current time because the alarm event already defined when to go off
3. Define the notification content such as message and intent to launch when cliked
4. Call the notification

String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) receiverContext.getSystemService(ns);

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, "Hello", System.currentTimeMillis());

CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";  
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";  
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(receiverContext, TargetActivity.class);  
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(receiverContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);  

notification.setLatestEventInfo(receiverContext, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);  

private static final int notificationID = 1;

mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
```

**EDIT 2**
[Creating notification at specified time using Alarm Manager](http://n8tech44.blogspot.com/2012/08/using-alarmmanager-to-schedule.html)

Comment: Okay, I followed the first tutorial but I'm getting the errors where 'ctx' cannot be resolved as a variable and getBroadcast is not applicable for the arguments

Comment: ctx in the example refers to the application context.  So change that to either "this" or "YourActivityName.this"

Comment: Thank you so much man! Do you know how I could make this into a notification?

Comment: Edited the post with a link to the status notification documentation, and a simplified version that I hope shows where things might differ by adding the notification from a broadcast receiver

Comment: Thank you so much, this is such a great help for me. 1 last question, its all right if you want to pass on answering, you've helped me plenty! Do you know how I would be able to activate this notification on a certain date and time?

Comment: You would set the date and time in an AlarmManager event like in first 2 tutorials then in your BroadcaseReceiver you would create the notification rather than sending a toast message or sms.  Any information you wanted your notification to have would need to be passed to the intent associated with the alarm so it could be extracted and used in your receiver class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost right now D': How would the creation and activation of the notification look other than the toast was?

Comment: Thank you so much, you really helped me out today. I see that you wrote this today too!

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
ArrayList<Calendar> alarmTimes = getAlarmTimes(); //Make your own function which returns alarm times as an array of Calendar type

for(int i=0; i<alarmTimes.size(); i++)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimes[i].getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

If you would like to handle each alarm independently, then use a different **requestCode** for each alarm.
Also, you might want to take a look at the different flags being used in **alarmManager.set()** function. Modify them according to your application needs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

You will have to make an AlarmReceiver class which will handle whatever you want to do when an alarm goes off (make sure to add this class in AndroidManifest as **receiver**). If you want to send extra info along with an alarm, then you use *intent extras* like this:

```
intent.putExtra("info1", value1);
intent.putExtra("info2", value2);
```

where **info1** is the name of the extra data, and value1 is the value which you send.

Hope this helps!

EDITED:

```
ArrayList<Calendar> alarmTimes = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(CALENDAR.MONTH, 7);
calendar.set(CALENDAR.DAY_OF_MONTH, 17);
calendar.set(CALENDAR.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
calendar.set(CALENDAR.MINUTE, 0);

alarmTimes.add(calendar);

//Repeat the above code for all alarm times and then return array object
return alarmTimes;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! What would an example be to fill in for the array for a date like August 17th at 1:00 PM ?